# Analysis question. Density in R

Tags: analysis

Prove that the set of rational numbers of the form $\frac{p}{2^n}$ for $p,n \in Z$ is dense in $R$.

I am given a definition;

A subset $U$ of $S$ is dense in $S$ if $\bar{U} = S$. Where $\bar{U}$ is the closure of $U$.

I know that if a,b are two real numbers then there is a rational number x such that a < x < b.

then, we can write $a < \frac{p}{2^n} < b$, therefore we can write $2^{n}a < p < 2^{n}b $...

I'm not sure what i am meant to show if i must be honest, i'd like to know what i am trying to show please. I have tried my best. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{\frac{p}{2^n}:n,p \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. It's enough if you prove that for any $a<b$ there exists $x \in A$, that $x \in [a,b]$.

You can do it this way: choose any $a<b$. There exists $n$ that $b-a<\frac{1}{2^n}$. Next there exists $p$ that:

$$\frac{p}{2^n} \leq a < \frac{p+1}{2^{n}}$$

If $a=\frac{p}{2^n}$ then $\frac{p}{2^n} \in [a,b]$, if not $\frac{p+1}{2^n}$ lies between $a$ and $b$, because:

$$\left|a-\frac{p+1}{2^n}\right|<\frac{1}{2^n}$$

So $\frac{p+1}{2^n} \in [a,b]$.

Comment: I think you want $\frac{p}{2^n}\leq a < \frac{p+1}{2^n}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $a<b$, can you find $n$ so that $\frac{1}{2^n}<b-a$?  Then argue that an integer multiple of $\frac{1}{2^n}$ falls between $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show the following: Given two reals $a<b$, we can find two integers $p,n$ with $a < \frac{p}{2^n} < b$.

You can argue like this:

Let $n$ be big enough, such that $2^n(b-a) > 1$. Thus we can find an integer between $2^na$ and $2^nb$...